# Change the case of a substitution

Tags: ruby

I've got the following: `text.gsub(/(lower) (upper)/, '\1 \2')`

Can I make just substitution `\2` uppercase?

Something like: `sed -e 's/\(abc\)/\U\1/'`

Is this possible in Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

see the gsub document:

str.gsub(pattern) {|match| block } → new_str

In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a parameter, and variables such as $1, $2, $`, $&, and $’ will be set appropriately. The value returned by the block will be substituted for the match on each call.

`"a lower upper b".gsub(/(lower) (upper)/){|s| $1 + " " + $2.upcase}`

Answer (score 2):

`gsub` takes a block argument, which is run for every match, passing in the match as the parameter--thus you can do whatever you like with it! For example, to capitalize every word in a string:

```
"ruby blocks are pretty awesome".gsub(/\w+/) do |match|
  match.capitalize
end
#=> "Ruby Blocks Are Pretty Awesome"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a newbie to Ruby - just began using it a few days ago but perhaps this would work? You'd be able to get the backreferences as the variables named `$n` in the bock:

```
new_text = text.gsub(/(lower) (upper)/){
    "#{$1} #{$2.upcase}"
}
```

**Update**
Looks like Brandon beat me to it by about 8 mins :) This is pretty much the same thing AFAIK